# Adding IsSelected property to EF POCO

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, inheritance, casting

I have a WCF service that uses EF to pass data to my Silverlight application.  I need to have users select multiple items from a combobox bound to an `ObservableCollection<SHOP>`.  I am trying to add an IsSelected property to the POCO on the Silverlight side to keep track of which items are selected.

I created a class called SHOPSelect which inherits from SHOP and added an IsSelected property.  I then changed the list that is bound to my combobox to that type.

My problem is trying to get the data from the WCF as an `ObservableCollection<SHOP>` and convert it to a list of my extended class `ObservableCollection<SHOPSelect>`.  I can get the code to compile using this, but an exception is thrown trying to cast SHOP to SHOPSelect when debugging.

```
Main.ShopList = new ObservableCollection<SHOPSelect>(e.Result.Cast<SHOPSelect>());
```

The exception is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'SHOP' to type 'SHOPSelect'.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Whats your Main.ShopList is it an ObservableCollection<SHOP> in which case that is your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several techniques available to solve your problem. I assume you have some kind of listbox with SelectionMode="Multiple" or "Extended" and you need to keep track of what is selected. I have to do this sometimes with displaying checkboxes inside listboxes.

First off, for your problem at hand, build a new observable collection this way (you'll need a constructor in SHOPSelect that takes a SHOP:

```
Main.ShopList = new ObservableCollection<SHOPSelect>(
  from shop in e.Result select new SHOPSelect(shop));
```

An alternate technique is to use Partial Classes to define IsSelected.

```
public partial class SHOP
{
    public bool IsSelected {get; set;}
}
```

Another technique is to restyle the ListBoxItemContainer. The default template used by Microsoft is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278062(v=VS.95).aspx Modify the ListBoxItem style by replacing

```
  <ContentPresenter
          x:Name="contentPresenter"
          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
```

with

```
    <CheckBox x:Name="contentControl" 
       IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,0,0,0" 
       IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}">
        <ContentPresenter Margin="6,0,0,0" 
           x:Name="contentPresenter" 
           ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
           Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
           HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" />
    </CheckBox>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I went with the partial class, adding it under the WCF's namespace

Answer (score 1):

Rather than inherit a new type, just extend the existing type (partial class) adding your own "silverlight only" properties - in this case "IsSelected".